# Не могу создать soap-клиента из локального wsdl-файла

Tags: node.js, soap

Согласно [документации](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap#soapcreateclientasyncurl-options---create-a-new-soap-client-from-a-wsdl-url-also-supports-a-local-filesystem-path) soap модуля для nodejs я могу подключать wsdl-файл не только по url но и из локальной файловой системы:

```
  var soap = require('soap');
  var url = 'http://example.com/wsdl?wsdl';
  var args = {name: 'value'};
  soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
      client.MyFunction(args, function(err, result) {
          console.log(result);
      });
  });
```

с url клиент создается без проблем, но у меня есть необходимость внести корректировки в wsdl-файл и поэтому мне нужна своя модифицированная версия. Как только вместо url я даю строку с относительным путем то после выполнения createClient в client возвращается undefined.

Подскажите что я делаю не так?

Comment: может стоит посмотреть что пишет в ошибке?

Comment: я же описал, что client не определен, разумеется нельзя вызвать ни один метод у undefined

Comment: так в колбеке `createClient` есть объект с ошибкой, в ней что?

Comment: спасибо, простите что туплю, все получилось.